# Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open()

Tags: php, sqlite

I tried to open sqlite db using below code,

```
$db = sqlite_open("tttt");
```

But it gives me an error,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open()
```

I have search this in different sites and do all the modifications `in .ini` file but doesn't work.

My php version is 5.3.13

Comment: check this extension in phpinfo()

Comment: could you pls explain a bit

Comment: create a blank page and call phpinfo() function in your script. then request this page in browser. it will show information about your php installation (available extensions etc.) sqllite should be there if it is installed correctly

Comment: so what the extension i need to chk

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable/install it. See [the docs for instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php) on how to do this.

Comment: extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll not found in my ini file

Comment: added them manually, just paste extension=php_pdo.dll extension=php_sqlite.dll in ini file. is it ok. else could you pls how to do it. i'm new to php. pls help me